# React can not get value of global variable

Tags: reactjs, components, global-variables

I am learning React and I dont understand how to make something like global aplication state.
I made a window.appState variale but I am not able to get the appState inside the components. It throws me an error appState is undefined. appState initiliazation looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './assets/index.scss';
import App from './App';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router
} from "react-router-dom";


let appState = {
    accessToken: ''
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and if I try to access appState in component it is undefined.

```
class Home extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)

        // window.appState is undefined???
        if( ! window.appState.accessToken ) this.props.history.push('/login')
    }

    .....

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `let appState = {}` sets that in the scope of the file. If you want to set it on `window` so that it is global you would instead do `window.appState = {}`.